# FullCalendar AllDaySlot replacement

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FC in a webapp to plan employeeshifts. My users add a slot and assign one or several employees to this slot (or they do it themself). This works like a charm.

Now I've been asked for a new feature - a "counter" placed in the top of each day (basicWeek,agendaWeek,agendaDay should have this).

This counter should show how many hours have been planned for this date and some other similar information.

My problem is how to either ADD a new TR in the THEAD - one for each day - or use the AllDaySlot which is where I would visually like it to be.
Currently I add a menu to the top of each day in agendaweek andbasicweek using the code below, I've tried to add a placeholder in the loop, but with no luck.

Looking forward to your intelligent input on this :D

```
if (view.name === 'agendaWeek' || view.name === 'basicWeek') {
                // Add the "dropdowns" to the day headers
                var $headers = $('.fc-widget-header.fc-sun, .fc-widget-header.fc-mon, .fc-widget-header.fc-tue, .fc-widget-header.fc-wed, .fc-widget-header.fc-thu, .fc-widget-header.fc-fri, .fc-widget-header.fc-sat, .fc-day-header.fc-sun, .fc-day-header.fc-mon, .fc-day-header.fc-tue, .fc-day-header.fc-wed, .fc-day-header.fc-thu, .fc-day-header.fc-fri, .fc-day-header.fc-sat');
                $headers.css('position', 'relative');
                $headers.each(
                    function(){
                        var _d = $(this).html().substring(4);
                        $(this).prepend("<div class='topdropdown' style='position: absolute; left: 0;' onmouseover='showDayMenu(\""+ _d +"\",this);'><span class='icon12 icomoon-icon-grid-view-2'></span></div>");
                        var _date = $(this).attr("class").match("fc-col[0-9]"));
                        //$(this).parent().find(".fc-widget-content").html("<div class='topcounter' style='position: absolute; left: 0;'>"+ _date +"</div>");
                    }
                );
            }
```

Edit 2013-08-14:
So I tried to add a new TR to the THEAD and the result was... well not quite as expected :)
I added a new TR to THEAD and inserted a orange bordered DIV as a placeholder, but the rows below didn't "move down" - am I really forced to alter the CSS for FC ?
http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/7743/31fv.png

Really hope one of you guys have the answer :?

Best regards,Mark

Comment: Well with my XP for example i had to alter code in the core of FC to, for each 1st day of the month add another text instead of number 1 only.

So i think you might need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but rather a work-around I used to accomplish the same task:

In my case, I returned a JSON array of the elements I wanted to add to the fullCalendar with start time end time title etc, but needed the daily hour values at the top (In the all day slot was preferrable).

I iterated through each day within my month range and added a new array object to my event object with only the total hours for that day and a start time along with a common attribute to distinguish these daily counters as such vs. an actual event.

When rendering the events to the calendar, I set allDay to true along with locking them up, e.g:

`{ 'title': item.Summary, 'start': item.Start, 'allDay': true,'startEditable': false, 'description': 'Counter' }`

The item.Summary is a string with the hour count from my server ("Hrs: [#]").

item.Start is set to midnight on the day of the counter.

This makes them non-draggable, small, and at the top of each day (regardless of view, naturally). I populate the array object with these counter objects first to ensure they are rendered at the top of the page.

Again, this doesn't directly address your question, however it does allow for the result you're looking for.

(I just spent a couple of hours getting this figured out/set up - first stack overflow post!)